# How to declare a function in Cocoa after the function using it?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, function, declaration

I'm slowly building my application to a working state.

I'm using two functions called `setCollection` and `addToCollection`. These functions both accept `NSArray` as input.

I also have a function called `add` in which I use both of these functions. When I try to compile, Xcode shows an error:

> 'setCollection' undeclared (first use in this function)

I guess this has to do with the function called being defined below the active function. Another guess would be that the functions should be globalized to be useable inside my `add` function.

I'm normally a php coder. the way Php handles this is the first one. The functions called should be before the functions using them, because otherwise they just don't exist. Is there a way to make functions still to come available at runtime, or should I rearrange all functions to make them function properly?

Comment: If you are creating a Cocoa application, you probably want to make use of objective-c classes and objects. Have you looked through Apple's developer documentation?
http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Cocoa/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your functions are global (not part of a class), you just have to put the declaration before the use, just like eJames suggests.

If your functions actually are methods (part of a class), you have to declare an anonymous category of your class before the implementation and put your method declarations in this interface:

```
@interface Myclass()
- (void) setCollection:(NSArray*)array;
- (void) addToCollection:(NSArray*)array;
@end

@implementation Myclass

// Code that calls setCollection or addToCollection

- (void) setCollection:(NSArray*)array
{
    // your code here
}

- (void) addToCollection:(NSArray*)array
{
    // your code here
}

@end
```

This way, you don't need to expose your functions in the main interface of `MyClass`.

Comment: Aas a follow-up to this question, do you know a site with beginner tutorials about how to link the array of arrays to a tableview inside IB? please PM me or something if so or if you personally know how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't check for your follow-up question, but a nice site with cocoa tutorials is http://cocoadevcentral.com/

Answer (score 8):

You can declare functions ahead of time as follows:

```
void setCollection(NSArray * array);
void addToCollection(NSArray * array);

//...

// code that calls setCollection or addToCollection

//...

void setCollection(NSArray * array)
{
    // your code here
}

void addToCollection(NSArray * array)
{
    // your code here
}
```

If you are creating a custom class, and these are member functions (usually called methods in Objective-C) then you would declare the methods in your class header and define them in your class source file:

```
//MyClass.h:
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{

}

- (void)setCollection:(NSArray *)array;
- (void)addToCollection:(NSArray *)array;

@end
```

```
//MyClass.m:

#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

- (void)setCollection:(NSArray *)array
{
    // your code here
}

- (void)addToCollection:(NSArray *)array
{
    // your code here
}

@end
```

```
//some other source file

#import "MyClass.h"

//...

MyClass * collection = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[collection setCollection:someArray];
[collection addToCollection:someArray];

//...
```

Comment: thanks. this was very helpful! together with the answer below (i Was using the function as accesors, referenceing them as - (void)) this actually got my application to work partly as I wanted.

Comment: @(whoever down-voted this): can you please tell me what was wrong with it? Thanks.